# Java GUI how to assign the created objects to the constructor in other classes?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying move the element created previously in other classes. How can I assign the object created to the constructor in the "Player" class and make the object drew in the GUI belongs to each player? The following codes are part of my codes. Please take a look and suggest some solutions. Thank You.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Gui extends JFrame {

    public Gui(){
        setTitle("Test");
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setSize(1000, 1000);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void addNewOval(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);    g2d.fillOval (865, 865, 30, 30);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawRect(50, 50, 900, 900);
    }
}

class Player{
    Gui a1;
    String name;
    int position;
    // add something?

    Player(String name){
        this.name = name;
        position = 0;
        // add something?
    }
    public void move(){
        position += 1;
        // Can the object in GUI move according to the position?
    }
}

public class Game{
    public static int totalPlayerNumber;
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Gui a1 = new Gui();
        System.out.println("How many players?");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        totalPlayerNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        Gui.addNewOval(a1.getGraphics(), totalPlayerNumber);

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPlayerNumber; i++){
            System.out.println("number " + i + " player's name: ");
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String temp = scanner.next();
            Player a = new Player(temp);
    }
}
```

I have tried to add " a1.addNewOval(a1.getGraphics()); " in the Player constructor but it showed NullPointerException when creating the Player object in main. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your `fillOval` method in your Gui class?

Comment: public static void fillOval(Graphics g) {
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2d.fillOval (865, 865, 30, 30);
 }
Should add this in that class?

Comment: You should add everything that you think would help answering the question.

Comment: Now I can create the oval based on the user input but how can I assign the created oval to each player? What should I add in the constructor in "Player" class?

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code? It will not compile. The `g2d` object within the `addNewOval` method does not exist at that scope level. Have you tried to compile/run your program to see where the bugs are?

Comment: Not to mention `#addNewOval` doesn't have an int param. You should do basic debugging at the very least before posting the question here - you might answer it yourself.